# Springboot postgres Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: postgresql, gradle, jdbc

I am trying to develop web application using SpringBoot and Postgres Database. However, on connecting to the application, I am getting error "Failed to determine a suitable driver class"
As per advise in older posts, I have tried using driver of different version of jdbc and also tried creating bean for NamedParameterJdbcTemplate manually. I also validated that libraries are present and is accessible from Java code and those are present in classpath. But its still giving the same issue.
I am using gradle to import all jars into build path.

Here is the git repository for the code:
https://github.com/ashubisht/sample-sbs.git

Gradle dependency code:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    //compile("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1206-jdbc42")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Code for building Bean

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Datasource {

    @Value("${db.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClass;
    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() throws Exception{
        System.out.println(driverClass+" "+ url+" "+username+" "+password);
        DriverManagerDataSource source = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        source.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        source.setUrl(url);
        source.setUsername(username);
        source.setPassword(password);
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(source);
        return namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

Here is application.properties

```
server.port=8086

#spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
#spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
#spring.datasource.username=postgres
#spring.datasource.password=password
#spring.datasource.platform=postgresql
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

db.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
db.username=postgres
db.password=password
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is resolved by creating two beans. Separate bean is created for DataSource and NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        System.out.println(driverClass+" "+ url+" "+username+" "+password);
        DriverManagerDataSource source = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        source.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        source.setUrl(url);
        source.setUsername(username);
        source.setPassword(password);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(){
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(this.dataSource());
        return namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: Where should we create those functions?

Comment: You need to create DataSource.java inside source package, to be scanned and picked by Springboot

Answer (score 10):

For me the issue was in a miss-spell for postgresSql

its only one s,

replace

1. spring.datasource.url=jdbc:**postgres**://localhost:5432/databaseName
2. spring.datasource.url=jdbc:**postgressql**://localhost:5432/databaseName

with
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:**postgresql**://localhost:5432/databaseName

also check the same thing on hibernate dialect,

replace `PostgresSQLDialect`
with  `PostgreSQLDialect`

Answer (score 3):

Please try it

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:postgresql://ip:port/datafeed?currentSchema=user_management
spring.r2dbc.username=username
spring.r2dbc.password=12345
spring.r2dbc.driver=postgresql
```

Hope to help you!

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem.
The solution for me was to change `application.properties` file extension into `application.yml`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. It happens when you install sts version 3.
I found the solution to this problem by doing trial & error method.
This error is occured due to the non-availability of the connection between Application Properties & the server. I got to know by changing the port number in the application Properties to 9090, later then while running the application the console showed the default port number 8080.
Thus you should maven clean and maven build your Spring Boot Application.
After the above step, you run your application normally as spring boot application, the database will get connected and the application will get started.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was

> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
> Consider the following:
> If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put
> it on the classpath.
> If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

and the issue was missing profile
so I added the following in the classpath and it worked

> spring.profiles.active=dev

Answer (score 0):

Also, the problem could be because of lack of `jdbc` dependency in your project. If you use `maven` add to `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```