# Spring boot application - Tomcat deployment - Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, tomcat

While running from IDE everything looks fine

Getting a below-mentioned error while trying to deploy the application in the tomcat server.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://dayrhebfmi001.enterprisenet.org:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot"}
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.6'
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.8'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.28'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '2.1.8.RELEASE'

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.platform=xxxxx
spring.datasource.url=xxxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxx
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: show us your application.properties file.

Comment: You should add the param spring.datasource.driver-class-name=

Comment: For example, if you are using postgresql: spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

Comment: The driver name is derrived from the JDBC url. Which means either the URL is wrong, or the driver isn't properly included in the artifact. `spring.datasource.platform` isn't a used property. Also stop mixing versions of Spring Boot you are including jars from 2.1.7 and 2.1.8 that will somewhere lead to errors. Next to that you should apply use the Spring Boot plugin as well to create a proper war.

Comment: @MychellTeixeira: Added driver name but still getting the error "Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Failed to determine a suitable driver class"

Comment: Try this ansswer:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403991/springboot-postgres-failed-to-determine-a-suitable-driver-class/51406154#51406154

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

There are a couple things that look suspicious about your properties.  But I think you can solve this specific error by giving it the class name as requested.

`spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`

(or whatever DB you're using)

Extra points for adding

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

(again, or whatever DB you're using)

EDIT:
Of course unless you've put the database driver jar file in tomcat/lib, you'll need to add that to your dependencies such that it can get bundled into the war file.

Comment: Added driver class name but still getting the error "Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Failed to determine a suitable driver class"

Answer (score 1):

You should add driver class configuration to application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```