# Error creating bean with name 'namedParameterJdbcTemplate', Failed to determine a suitable driver class, trying to run a web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, azure-sql-database

I am trying to run a spring mvc webapp that connects to an azure sql db. I am having problems with the configuration required to set up the connection (there were no issues with the servlet until I added the application.properties file and attempted to configure a database connection). I am getting the following error when deploying my .war file (compilation is normal):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:715)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:590)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:233)
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:174)
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43)
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:85)
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1b59b1ff.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>)
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1b59b1ff$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e08cfaf5.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1b59b1ff.dataSource(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:715)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:590)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=xxxServer;user=user@xxxxx;password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
```

My build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'   
    id "lenala.azure.azurewebapp" version "1.0"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test' 
//compile("org.springframework:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")

compile("org.springframework:spring-beans")
compile("com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.8.0")
//compile("com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.4.0.jre7")
//compile("com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.1.0.jre13-preview")

//compile("org.springframework:spring-dao:2.0.8")
compile("javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0.2")
compile("com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:7.4.1.jre8")
compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")

compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa")

   compile("org.springframework:spring-context")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-webmvc")
     compile("org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.7.4")

    compile("org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.8.Final")

     compile("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
    compile("javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5")
    compile("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2")
    compile("javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.2")    
    compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5")
    compile("org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5")
    compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5")
    compile("log4j:log4j:1.2.17")

    testCompile("junit:junit:4.7") 

}

azureWebApp {
    resourceGroup = 'BetApp'
    appName = 'BetApp'
    pricingTier = "S1"
    appService = {
        type = 'linux'
        runtimeStack = 'TOMCAT 9.0-jre8'
    }
    authentication = {
        type = "file"
        file = "my.azureauth"
    }

    deployment = {
        type = "war"
        // if 'warFile' is not specified, default output of the 'war' plugin will be used
         warFile = 'build/libs/SpringMVCExample.war'
        //contextPath = 'todoapp'
    }
}

apply plugin: "war"
war {
    baseName = 'SpringMVCExample'
}
```

my UserRespository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;



@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {}
```

Project structure:

[image]

I have looked through similar answers and attempted to use several various versions of drivers, but none have worked. Any suggestions or solutions to this would be greatly appreciated!

Project code on github:
https://github.com/ArikRiz/BetApp

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? Based on the Gradle build configuration, I am assuming, you are using Java 7. If that is true, can you try using 

compile("com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.4.0.jre7")

or relevant java version of the driver and let me know if you are still having issues.

Comment: Hi Ramu, I should be using Java 8, thank you for bringing that to my attention. I updated the gradle file respectively, but neither the 6.4.0.jre7 or the 8.1.0.jre13 drivers worked still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the driver class property to

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Also use appropriate JDBC driver version based on the Java version. See version compatibility here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hi Ramu, thank you for your suggestion. I attempted this, but there was no change, the same error was thrown. I added the correct version in the build.gradle file as well, to no avail.

Comment: @Arik At this point, its very hard for me to say exactly what the issue is without looking at the parts of your code. Can you please share your project structure and **UserRepository** class as well. Other thing you can try is, instead of relying on Spring boot to create the dataSource bean, you can create the bean yourself. See the stackoverflow question related to [Creating DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403991/springboot-postgres-failed-to-determine-a-suitable-driver-class)

Comment: I attempted to create my own beans, but that did not work either, with the same error being thrown. I am truly confused as to why this is still happening, as the driver is the correct version, with the correct syntax, in the correct location, but is still not being read correctly. Im guessing that the issue is where the configuration is reading the driver class from, as the driver I have in the application.properties should be the correct one.

Comment: @Arik Sorry that didn't work out. Let try another one. It seems like you are including_tomcat-jdbc_ jar in your application. Find that dependency and exclude it. This way Spring uses Hikari datasource instead of Tomcat datasource.

Comment: I believe I have actually already done this, I forgot to update the error message in my original post. I updated it now, but it appears that spring is indeed using Hikari datasource, but with no change to the error

Comment: @Arik can share your project using github?

Comment: I just added the link

Comment: @Arik Can you try changing your java version to 1.8?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202286/discussion-between-ramu-and-arik).

Answer (score 1):

have you tried explicitely including:

```
compile("org.springframework:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
```

in your dependencies?

Comment: HI rmalchow, I tried this, but there was no change. I could not add exactly what you mentioned, however, instead I had to add org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc